# Calling a c# method trough Ajax without using static methods

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am doing a website where I have to use ajax and was wondering if there is a way to call a method from the server side with out setting the method to static. I researched this but every example I found has the method set as static and was wondering if you could this with using static here is my code

Ajax Code:

```
function GetAddColour(id, Name) {

    var dataValue = { "id": id, "Name": Name }

    $.ajax({
        url: "AddColour.aspx/btnAddColour",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataValue,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
}
```

The C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void btnAddColour(int id, string Name)
{
    //do things to add colour
}
```

Is there a way to this without static method and also I cannot use update panels.

Comment: You need to understand how HTTP works.  Your page doesn't exist.  You're used to the ASP.Net ViewState, which carries along the page for you.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to know because some things like context to get the user logged in info would not work in static. Sorry if this is a dumb question kinda new to asp.net and web in general i am more focused on c++ and c and java so these things are new to me

Comment: see the below answer. Gives output as you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods you can access the `Session` object, so if you store your logged in user name in `Session["User"]`, then you could do something like this:

Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string GetLoggedInUserName()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Session["User"].ToString();
}
```

Markup:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "AddColour.aspx/GetLoggedInUserName",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
            // Need to de-reference the JSON via the .d
            alert(result.d);
        }
        else
        {
            // No .d; no de-reference necessary
            alert(result);
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
});
```

---

> Note: The `.d` syntax was an anti-XSS protection put in by Microsoft in the ASP.NET 3.5 release of ASP.NET AJAX; therefore the check to see if the .d property is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using web forms rather than ASP.Net MVC, you can create a `*.ashx` HttpHandler. It's just like a `*.aspx` page, but much much simpler. Your code-behind just has to implement the `IHttpHandler` interface (1 method, `ProcessRequest()` and 1 property `IsReusable`). If you require access to session state, you'll also need to "implement" (a misnomer, since these are both marker interfaces with nothing to implement) either `IReadonlySessionState` (read-only access) or `IRequiresSessionState` (read/write access).

However, you're responsible for pretty much everything from soup to nuts here. You can return JSON, binary image data, whatever your little heart desires.

Answer (score 0):

modify your datavalue to this.

```
var dataValue = "{id :'" + id + ", Name :'"+ Name "'}" ;
```

where id and name are two variables which have integer and string value respectively.
Ensure id to be integer, if it is not then change it to Number(id)

Javascript :

```
function GetAddColour(eid, eName) {
   var id = Number(eid);
   var Name = eName;
   var dataValue = "{id :'" + id + ", Name :'"+ Name "'}" ;
    $.ajax({
           url: "AddColour.aspx/btnAddColour",
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           data: dataValue,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (msg) {
                alert("Success");
           },
           error: function () { alert(arguments[2]); }      
        });
 }
```

and your C# web method should be

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static void btnAddColour(int id, string Name)
{
    // Your code here
}
```